# Chain different return in Mockito for retryWhen call

Tags: java, mockito, rx-java, rx-android

I'm creating unit tests for my RxJava observables in Android.

I want to chain return values from a mock and simulate error/resume values  in a observable.

I'm doing this:

```
when(repository.getObservable())
            .thenReturn(Observable.error(new Exception()))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(driver));
```

My observable:

```
return repository.getObservable()
            .retryWhen(observale -> {
                 return observable
                        .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), Pair::create)
                        .flatMap(o -> {
                             if (o.second < count) {
                               return Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                             }
                             return Observable.error(o.first);
            })))
```

But I only receive the `Observable.error(new Exception())`, even calling the `retryWhen` method 3+ times.

Did somebody know how can I test the re-emission of a different observable to test the `retryWhen` operator?

Comment: This blog post also talks about this (at the end): https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/testing-asynchronous-rxjava-code-using-mockito-8ad831a16877

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`retryWhen()` won't call `repository.getObservable()` a second time. Instead, it takes the `Observable.error()` that was returned the first time and resubscribes to it.

In order to use `retryWhen()` in this way, you'd have to return a single `Observable` that returns an error the first time it's subscribed to and does not do so in subsequent subscriptions. For example, you could do something like this:

```
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
  boolean hasBeenSubscribedTo = false;

  @Override public Observable<String> call() {
    if (!hasBeenSubscribedTo) {
      hasBeenSubscribedTo = true;
      return Observable.error(new Exception());
    }
    return Observable.just("Hello, world!");
  }
})
.retryWhen(/* ...etc... */)
```

Comment: Amazing Daniel! I tried to use defer but without the logical return, nice catch! Thanks much.

Comment: I use `fromCallable` instead of `defer` to have a bit less code (don't have to wrap the results with an `Observable`).

Comment: Is there any other solution? This answer means I should add useless code which is only needed for testing.